# Allocating memory for parameters given in constructors' class

Tags: c++, constructor

Let's suppose, we've got a class in which we have to make constructor that will allocate memory for its parameters, i.e. according to their values.

I guess I've might messed up a little bit but at least I gave it a go.

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std; 

class Person
{ 
   private: 
      int height 
      int age; 

   public: 
      Person(int height, int age){}
}; 

Person::Person(int *height, int *age)
{ 
   int *height1 = new int; 
   int *age = new int; 
}
```

Is it any good or utterly hopeless attempt ?

Comment: Your members are plain ints but you're using `new int` and allocating to `int *` why?

Comment: Your signatures don't match, it should be `Person::Person(int height_, int age_)`.

Comment: Also your constructor arguments are completely different between the declaration and the definition and won't compile

Comment: Also, your ctor is not exception-safe, it will leak the first allocation if the second throws. Consider using smart-pointers (preferably `std::unique_ptr`).

Comment: Could you describe more clearly what you want to achieve? It seems like a very roundabout way of trying to initialise an object. For instance, why do you pass pointers to the constructor of `Person`?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking. Memory is allocated automatically for the member variables (in the class instance) and the constructor parameters (on the stack); what are you trying to achieve with pointers and `new`?

Comment: I would like to build a constructor that will allocate memory for an array of let's say ints, the size of an array supposed to be indicated by constructor parameters. I guess, it's clear now :)

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, the signatures don't match.
Also, if you just want to store the passed values, there's no need to use new.

You could do

```
Person::Person(int h, int a)
{ 
   this->height = h; 
   this->age = a; 
}
```

or, a bit shorter:

```
Person::Person(int h, int a) : height(h), age(a) {}
```

Comment: There's even no need to use `this->` as long the parameter names don't collide with the member variable names.